# OpenLayers 3 displays WMTS tiles slightly downscaled

Tags: openlayers, tiles, wmts

I'm having trouble with a WMTS source in my OpenLayers 3-driven web application.

The map is shown and the layer is rendered, but the 256x256 px tiles are rendered slightly downscaled. For instance, the section covered by this tile

[image: Raw tile]

looks like this when screen grabbed from the map

[image: Rendered tile]

(216x216 px)

The source in question is set up using WMTS' getCapabilities, so there's minimal manual labour going on:

```
function getSource(getCapabilitiesUrl) {
    var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();
    return fetch(getCapabilitiesUrl)
        .then(function (resp) {
            return resp.text();
        })
        .then(function (xml) {
            return parser.read(xml);
        })
        .then(function (wmtsCap) {
            return new ol.source.WMTS(ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(wmtsCap, {
                layer: 'my-layer',
                matrixSet: 'EPSG:32633'
            }));
        });
}
```

The projection is defined like this:

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:32633', '+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs');
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can get OpenLayers to display the tiles at the right scale (i.e. unscaled)?

The problem exists in a clean environment without any CSS styling, so this should not be the source of the problem. I'd make a live demo for you to try, but the geoserver is unfortunately not available to the public.

**EDIT**

This is the (anonymised) request for the 256x256 tile shown at the top of the post:
`https://example.com/geowebcache/service/wmts?layer=my-layer&‌​style=&tilematrixset‌​=32633&Service=WMTS&‌​Request=GetTile&Vers‌​ion=1.0.0&Format=ima‌​ge%2Fpng&TileMatrix=‌​32633%3A5&TileCol=9&‌​TileRow=12`

Comment: What request is actually sent to the WMTS service?

Comment: @nmtoken: For the example tile in the post: `https://example.com/geowebcache/service/wmts?layer=my-layer&style=&tilematrixset=32633&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix=32633%3A5&TileCol=9&TileRow=12`

Comment: and when you run that request in a browser is the result a 256x256 image

Comment: @nmtoken Yep, the response would be the same as the first example png in the post.

Comment: So the problem doesn't appear to be with the code that generates the request, or the projection, or the service, it must be with your client.   Could you have a CSS stylesheet that is shrinking images/content by 85%

Comment: @nmtoken Yes, I'm sure there's some false assumption being made by OL3, I just have no idea what that might be. There's no styling at all, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Could you add all the additional information you've added in the comments to your question.

Comment: @nmtoken Sure thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the view not having the correct maximum resolution.

Given the `getSource` function above, I get a good result by setting up the view like this:

```
var source = getSource("http://example.com/wms?REQUEST=getcapabilities");
var tileGrid = source.getTileGrid();
var view = new ol.View({
    projection = source.getProjection(),
    maxResolution: tileGrid.getResolution(tileGrid.getMinZoom());
});
```